# Excel Date format to number in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, date

I have a question:

I have the current date in a cell with date format like:

```
5/12/2018
```

When I formatting this cell to a number (right click -> cell format -> number), I got this:

```
43439,67
```

How can I get this number in Java? I tried:

```
Date fecha = new Date();
System.out.println(fecha.getTime());
```

The result was:

```
1544043888569
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I guess it is the number days since `1/1/1900`.

Comment: You can read more about how Excel does this on : https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time

Comment: Handling Excel date-time values in Java has been asked and answered many times. Always search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Yes... but not the way as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Excel Date and Time 101](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time) this number
is defined as the number of days since 31-Dec-1899.

[`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) of a `Date` returns the number of milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970.
From that you can easily calculate the number of days since 31-Dec-1899.

```
Date fecha = new Date();
double days = fecha.getTime() / 1000.0 / 86400 + 70 * 365.25 + 1;
System.out.println(days);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result with the modulus operator:

```
Date fecha = new Date();
double secs = (fecha.getTime() % 86400000) / 1000.;
System.out.println(secs);
```

Comment: Close! that returns: 78909,391